# How to set and get values from an Object that exists in an ArrayList<Verbs>

Tags: java, object, arraylist, getter-setter

I'm trying to make an array of objects called Verbs.

The Verb class has 4 Strings.

```
public class Verb {
    String maori;
    String englishPast;
    String englishPresent;
    String englishFuture;
}
```

Do I need to write get and set methods into this class in order to change these values or does android handle it for you somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to not be an Android problem but a java related question. You should create a Verb class like this:

```
public class Verb {
    private String maori;
    //All other strings you need

    public String getMaori() {
        return maori;
    }

    //Add a setter as well
```

Then you should create your Verb objects and add these objects to your array. But this has nothing to do with Android at all!

Comment: The person wouldn't really need getters and setters becauase he didn't declare his fields as private, but you could makes sense.

Comment: Yeah i know he didn't but I think using getter and setter methods is a better practice.

Comment: Sorry not sure how, trying to figure out now.